# Returning a Formatted Number in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a number value that is pulled from a mysql database to be formatted differently in a php document.

```
        $oIteminfo = mysql_query("
    SELECT Items.PartID, Items.VendorCost, Items.ProductName, Sum(Sales.AmountSold) AS SumOfAmountSold
    FROM Items 
    LEFT JOIN Sales 
    ON Items.PartID = Sales.PartID
    GROUP BY Items.PartID, Items.VendorCost, Items.ProductName
    HAVING Items.PartID=$iPartID;


") or die(mysql_error()); 


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oIteminfo)) 
    { 
    ECHO "<h1>WOWAuctionSales</h1>";
    ECHO "<img src=\"http://www.wowauctionsales.com/images/".$iPartID.".jpg\"height='35' width='35'>";
    ECHO "<h1>".$row['ProductName']."</h1><br>";  
    ECHO "<B>Total Sold:</B>".$row['SumOfAmountSold']."<br>";
    ECHO "<B>Vendor Price:</B>".$row['VendorCost']."<br>";
```

For example in one instance the result will pull the following number 162356 I want that number to be formatted to say 16g 23s 56c or 00g 00s 00c I have looked a fprintf, sprintf and printf, but they do not seem to do the trick. I have seen this formatting done before in php but I cannot seem to figure it out how to do it myself.

Comment: What units of measurement are "g", "s", and "c" ?  Are you just wanting those letters appended to the first pair, second pair, and third pair of numbers?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @DavidWhite it stand for gold silver and copper. So some items would result in 13g 24s 84c and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can think of a dozen options here is one

```
//$number ="162356";
$number =$row['VendorCost'];
echo substr($number,0,2).'g '.substr($number,2,2).'s '.substr($number,4,2).'c';
```

Comment: If it's a string, yes, and also has exactly the right number of digits.

Comment: I think it's more like a "days/hours/minutes/seconds" problem where the number needs to be split up into different parts. "Ones", "Hundreds" and "Tens of thousands" in this case.

Comment: @Dagon The number is a variable so how would I go about separating a variable so on any given page it will have a different number as a result. Sometimes it would be something like 005428 and 125430.

Comment: `$number` is a variable, just replace that with yours

Comment: @Dagon so if I am understanding it correctly it would like something like this?  ;
 $number = ['VendorCost'];
 echo substr($number,0,2).'g '.substr($number,2,2).'s '.substr($number,4,2).'c';

Comment: inn your case `$number =$row['VendorCost'];` then the rest as above